# center 2 views vertically in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have 2 views which I need to center vertically (both).
I need to have fixed top margin between the 2 views (40 dp) 
How can I do it with ConstraintLayout?

Thanks.

Comment: Chain the top one to the top of the parent, the bottom one to the bottom of the parent, and also chain them together. Then set chainstyle as packed on the top one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use chains, in this case `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` will achieve what you're looking for.

Try something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_view_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="TextView 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_1" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```